# After removing a line from my .gitignore file, git still ignores the files

Tags: git, gitignore

I inherited a git repo that had `*.dll` in the gitignore file, however I now need to add dll files to the repo.  After having removed the `*.dll` line from the .gitignore file, running `git add name.dll` in order to add it to the git repo I get

```
The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
escomm.dll
Use -f if you really want to add them.
```

also running `git status` does not show any of the dll's that are in the project

Is this expected behavior, if so why? Is there anyway to make git show when a new *.dll file has been added using git status? And not require the `-f` option to add it?

Comment: I suspect that there may be another `.gitignore` file which is still enforcing the rule.

Comment: Learned something new about git, you can have a global ignore file, and that was setting it to be ignored there.  using git check-ignore helped me find this if anyone else runs into this issue

Comment: The harder (and more confusing) problem actually is when you want to ignore a file which has already been added.

Comment: Yea I found a lot of answers on how to do that, which made searching for my problem a lot more challenging since most of the keywords are about the same.  Your comment did make me realize that there has to be a way to debug a gitignore file, which ultimately led me to my answer :)

Comment: `git status --ignored` could show the ignored untracked files. You need to check .git/info/exclude, and core.excludesFile in `git config --global or --system or <empty> -l`, and .gitignore.

Answer (score 0):

To understand why that dll file is *still* ignore, use [`git check-ignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore):

```
 git check-ignore -v -- escomm.dll
```

You will see why removing `*.dll` from your `.gitignore` might not have been enough.